# Complex foreach with smarty to display bootstrap carousel

Tags: zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I am going to implement twitter bootstrap's carousel in order to display five items at once. My system uses the template engine smarty.

I am already familiar with smarty basics. The following code would display all my items:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
{foreach $items as $item}
    <li class="span2">
        <div class="caption">
            <h5>{$item.title}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{$item.image}" alt="">
        </div>
    </li>        
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Unfortunately twitter bootstrap's carousel needs all the items separated into blocks, like that:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <div class="item active">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span2 offset1">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span2 offset1">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
            <li class="span2">...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...
  </ul>
```

How do I achieve this by using smarty's foreach loop:

- Putting 5 items into one div.item the next 5 items into the next div.item and so on
- The first div.item should get the class 'active'
- The first item in every div.item should get the class '.offset1'

Comment: For ZF1's view I'd suggest a [partial loop](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial), for SMARTY your on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty defines some magic variables which allow you to see how many times the loop has gone through (see [the documentation for `{foreach}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) for all the details).

In your case you want to check:

- `{$item@first}` to open the first, active div.item
- `{$item@iteration is div by 5}` to close and open the next div.item, and give its first li the `offset1` class
- `{$item@last}` to close off the last div.item whether or not it's divisible by 5